# Angular2: how to properly implement 2-way databinding without incurring in endless loop

Tags: typescript, angular

Still continuing my Angular2 (beta 1) newcomer journey, I'm trying to understand how to properly implement 2-way binding without having my app stuck in an endless loop.

Please find the sample repro at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/83NeiUCEpPvYvUXIkl0g . Just run and click the button.

My scenario:

- a directive wraps the Ace code editor and exposes a `text` property and a `textChanged` event.
- an (XML) editor component uses this directive. It should be able to respond to changes in the underlying editor to update its XML code, and to set a new text in the underlying editor from its XML code.

My problem is that whenever the editor component programmatically sets its `xml` property, this triggers the change in the underlying Ace editor, which in turn triggers the text-changed event, which in turn is handled by the editor component's callback, and so forth. This generates an endless loop and you can see the editor's text flicker. What I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the code for the directive:

```
import {Component,Directive,EventEmitter,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
declare var ace: any;

@Directive({
    selector: "ace-editor",
    inputs: [
        "text"
    ],
    outputs: [
        "textChanged"
    ]
})
export class AceDirective { 
    private editor : any;
    public textChanged: EventEmitter<string>;

    set text(s: string) {
        if (s === undefined) return;
        let sOld = this.editor.getValue();
        if (sOld === s) return;        
        this.editor.setValue(s);
        this.editor.clearSelection();
        this.editor.focus();
    }

    get text() {
        return this.editor.getValue();
    }

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        var dir = this;
        this.textChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

        let el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.editor = ace.edit(el);
        let session = this.editor.getSession();
        session.setMode("ace/mode/xml");
        session.setUseWrapMode(true);

        this.editor.on("change", (e) => {
            let s = dir.editor.getValue();
            dir.textChanged.next(s);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the editor component:

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
import {AceDirective} from "./ace.directive";

@Component({
    selector: "my-editor",
    directives: [AceDirective],
    template: `<div style="border:1px solid red">
    <ace-editor id="editor" [text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged($event)"></ace-editor>
    </div>
    <div><button (click)="changeXml()">set xml</button></div>`,
    inputs: [
        "xml"
    ]
})
export class EditorComponent { 
    private _xml: string;

    // using a property here so that I can set a breakpoint
    public set xml(s: string) {
        this._xml = s; 
    }
    public get xml() : string {
        return this._xml;
    }

    constructor() {
        this._xml = "";
    }

    public onXmlChanged(xml: string) {
        this._xml = xml;
    }

    // an action which somehow changes the XML content
    public changeXml() {
        this._xml = "<x>abc</x>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do the [(ngModel)]="property" syntax. Even though it looks to behave as the old two-way binding in reality is breaking it up into two different one way bindings, one for input and one for output, the way Angular 2 handles changes and his dirty check cycles under the hood is what changed and will not allow you to do an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this but it does not seem to work, unless of course my change was wrong (<ace-editor id="editor" [(ngModel)]="xml"></ace-editor>). When clicking on the set button nothing happens. Instead, when loading the page, I get an "EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' in [xml in EditorComponent@1:28]". I updated my Plunker accordingly, you can check it.

Comment: I must add that, as for the unclear error message, I found this hint: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4733, i.e. I had to explicitly import the NgModel directive (while others like NgFor are already incapsulated). I updated the Plunker, but it still behaves the same. Any idea?

Comment: Use text, not ngModel: `<ace-editor id="editor" [(text)]="xml"></ace-editor>`

Comment: Thanks Mark, I had not seen that after hours of reading "ngModel" in web pages... :) Fixed the Plunker now

Comment: @Naftis, I probably should have said more in my comment... you can use the `[(x)]` syntax for any property, but your component needs an `x` input property and an `xChange` output property (EventEmitter).  What I don't understand is why does `[(text)]` work in your scenario, but splitting it up doesn't: `[text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged($event)"`.  I thought they were equivalent.  Maybe Angular is doing the property binding and the event binding in one change detection cycle when the `[(x)]` syntax is used??

Comment: Sorry, another issue now: it seems that the xml property does not get updated anymore. See it for yourself by reopening the Plunker, I added a diagnostic div with interpolated {{xml}} and it does not display anything. It seems that text flows from the editor to the directive OK, but not in the other sense. Still stuck :(, but at least this can be related to your question: effectively, [(text)] does NOT work :).

Comment: I got an answer from the Google groups here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/TVYXuxRRs-k . It's essentially a hack, but it seems that there is a race condition otherwise. Thanks to Michael Corbridge for this. Just add a check in the directive event emitter and use emit instead of next: if(s.length !== 0) { this.textChanged.emit(s); }. Hope the released version of Angular will take care of this.